# Dangers of php file inside an iframe?

Tags: php, html, iframe

After realising that my web server wouldn't run php inside my html file I used an iframe which points to my php script.

It works as expected and now my site has a nice little comment form that the user can fill in and submit.

I opted for this instead of changing my hhtpd.conf because I don't think my web host allows it.

So my question is; is there any real danger of doing this? If the comment.php file were to mysteriously disappear an error would appear in my html which wouldn't affect the rest of my code. I can't think of any drawbacks unless there some server overhead I'm unaware of.

Any information would be welcomed.

Cheers!

Comment: on which server does the iframe run than?

Comment: It's on the same server as my html.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: The iframe src is a php file on the same server as my html. There is only one server involved in this scenario. I'm just curious if there are any security or performance issue involved.

Comment: There really is no question here. You don't _run_ PHP in an iFrame. You _display_ the output (HTML) generated by the PHP execution (on the _server_) in an iFrame. There is extra _overhead_ when using an iFrame though. Instead of the browser making one HTTP GET request to the server it now does two: one for the main page and another for the one the iFrame is displaying.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu. It was more just curiosity than anything else. Apologies if my question was a bit nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they (the html and php files) are located on the same server — should be no danger.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks Oleg!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify :

If you can 'run' the php in an iFrame, then you're able to run it in the main frame as well. the php that is generated for your iframe could as well be generated for the main frame.

So, no, there is no danger at at, but no, you don't need an iframe, I think you misunderstood somehow how php is working.

There is no php in html, php is (simplified) used in 2 scenarios : 
first is to generate html that will be sent to the web browser,
the second is a script, that doesn't render any php but affects some internal files, like databases and such.